# html agility, parse div html

Tags: html, c#-4.0, html-agility-pack

I have a html page which i am processing using html agility, here is the structure of the page. 
The div class is "show1","show2" and so on. yes the name remains same. How can I load all the divs which have name as song_html or class with "show"+number and then the value of each internal divs (songinfo, title, and hyperlinke value.)

```
<div id="container">

<div class="show1" id="song_html">
  <div class="left">
  Info1             
  </div>
<div id="right_song">
  <div style="font-size:15px;">
       <b>Song Title</b>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;">
            <a style="color:green;" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" 
            href="linktofile">Download</a>     
   </div> 
</div>                      
</div>                      


<div class="show2" id="song_html">
  <div class="left">
  Info2             
  </div>
<div id="right_song">
  <div style="font-size:15px;">
       <b>Song Title 2</b>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;">
            <a style="color:green;" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" 
            href="linktofile">Download</a>     
   </div> 
</div>                      
</div>                      


</div>
```

Help will be appreciated. This is what i have done so far.

```
  var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") &&   d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("show"));

foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
                {


}
```

Regards
Paraminder

Comment: You have multiple divs with `id="right_song"` and `id="song_html"`, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var songs = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
    .Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("show"))
    .Select(d => new 
    {
        Song = d.Descendants("div").First().InnerText.Trim(),
        Title = d.Descendants("div").ElementAt(1).Descendants("div").First().InnerText.Trim(),
        Link = d.Descendants("div").ElementAt(1).Descendants("a").First().Attributes["href"].Value.Trim()
    });

foreach (var songInfo in songs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Song: {0} Title: {1} Link: {2}", songInfo.Song, songInfo.Title, songInfo.Link);
}
```

Output:

```
Song: Info1 Title: Song Title   Link: linktofile
Song: Info2 Title: Song Title 2 Link: linktofile
```

Comment: works like charm. thanks a lot. I wish i could give you 10 up votes.